# Trouble hiding div at document ready

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im programming a website where you can chat with eachother, but I don't want my visiters to be redirected when they want to go to another page. So the url will always be like myurl.com wihtout any slashes. The only way to that (without using Flash) is to show and hide divs, but that's the problem. I've tried many times, and searched the internet for help, but nothing solved my problem. When you load the page, only the `#content_home` should be visible, and when you click a button in the nav that div should be showing. *I've used random pictures from the internet, just to fill in the divs.* Here's my (not working) code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<div id="nav_menu">
<button id="home">Home</button>
<button id="chat">Chat</button>
<button id="contact">Contact</button>
</div>
<div id="content_home">
<!-- Content center -->
<img src="http://hostgatordomains.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/why-need-img-2.png">
</div>
<div id="content_chat">
<img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg">
</div>
<div id="content_contact">
<img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg">
</div>
</center>
</body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#home').click(function(){
$('#content_home').show();
$('#content_chat').hide();
$('#content_contact').hide();
});
});
$('#chat').click(function(){
$('#content_home').hide();
$('#content_chat').show();
$('#content_contact').hide();
});
$('#contact').click(function(){
$('#content_home').hide();
$('#content_chat').hide();
$('#content_contact').show();
});
</script>
<style>
#content_home {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#content_chat {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

button {
    color: black;
    background-color: #F0E6EE;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #C2BCC1;
    cursor: pointer;

}
#content_center {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    left: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #787880;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to learn some basics on HTML before messing around with jQuery

Comment: I'm programming HTML for more than 1.5 years now, and jQuery came in recently, and I'm not the best in jQuery, I know, but I'm still learning.

Comment: @MoosMas Some comments it is just best to ignore. Most people are here to help, ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The only way to that (without using Flash) is to show and hide divs.

I would say this is incorrect, you can do this a lot of ways without loading the content of your entire site on one page. With that said to do it the way you've implemented it. Start by taking @M.Doye comment and fix your bracketing on document ready, as it stands you're only binding one within the ready method.

Second, change the functions up a bit, I suspect you don't want tabs to just toggle when you click something, but would rather have the code show a tab at a time.

Something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').click(function(){
        $('.contentTab').hide(); // Hide all tabs with class contentTab
        $('#content_home').show(); // Show only the tab you want to show
    });
    $('#chat').click(function(){
        $('.contentTab').hide();
        $('#content_chat').show();
    });
    $('#contact').click(function(){
        $('.contentTab').hide();
        $('#content_contact').show();
    });
  
    // A single method to do all the above if button id="xyz" then show element "content_" + button pressed id
    // You can use this instead of the 3 methods above, note the buttons now have class contentButton
    $('.contentButton').click(function(){
        $('.contentTab').hide(); 
        $('#content_' + $(this).attr('id')).show(); 
        console.log('#content_' + $(this).attr('id'))
    });
  
    // Show the first page
    $('#content_home').show(); 
});
```

```css
#content_home {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#content_chat {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

button {
    color: black;
    background-color: #F0E6EE;
}
button:hover {
    background-color: #C2BCC1;
    cursor: pointer;

}
#content_center {
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: left;
    left: 50px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #787880;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.contentTab {
    /* Hide all content to start the page */
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <center>
   <div id="nav_menu">
    <button id="home" class="contentButton">Home</button>
    <button id="chat" class="contentButton">Chat</button>
    <button id="contact" class="contentButton">Contact</button>
    <button id="generic" class="contentButton">Generic</button>
   </div>
   <div id="content_home" class="contentTab">
    <!-- Content center -->
    <img src="http://hostgatordomains.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/why-need-img-2.png">
   </div>
   <div id="content_chat" class="contentTab">
    <img src="http://www.apicius.es/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/IMG-20120714-009211.jpg">
   </div>
   <div id="content_contact" class="contentTab">
    <img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg">
   </div>
   <div id="content_generic" class="contentTab">
    <img src="http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/ImageProcessing2/img.jpg">
   </div>
  </center>
 </body>

</html>
```

Alternatively you can load different pages into contentHome using an Ajax to get the contents of each page, and load a page's contents into a div one page at a time so that the user never leaves the page, but only gets served the content they want, when they want it.

Edit: left the console.log in, you should probably take that out. :)

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way is to just add `style="display:none;"` inline to the divs you do not want displayed onload, the jQuery will handle the rest:

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/dwLgLogb/4/)

Also, your jQuery is not closed correctly: (You would have noticed this had you used the correct indentation)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').click(function(){
        $('#content_home').show();
        $('#content_chat').hide();
        $('#content_contact').hide();
    });
    $('#chat').click(function(){
        $('#content_home').hide();
        $('#content_chat').show();
        $('#content_contact').hide();
    });
    $('#contact').click(function(){
        $('#content_home').hide();
        $('#content_chat').hide();
        $('#content_contact').show();
   });
}); // close here
```